# What does a modem actually know?

Tags: mac-address, docsis

In a given setup:

```
                  -> device 1
modem -> router -|
                  -> device 2
```

Device 1 is wired and Device 2 is wireless.

1. Does modem know the MAC addresses of devices 1 & 2?
2. Does modem know the IP addresses of devices?

Thanks,
I am a beginning networking student.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: The **modem does not see the MAC addresses** of the devices connected to the router. When a packet is routed from a device to the modem, the router will create a new ethernet frame to forward the packet to the modem, using its own MAC as the source address.

Q2: If the router is doing **only routing**, the **modem will see the IP addresses** of the devices since source and destination IP addresses in the packet remain unchanged. But if your router is performing **network address translation** (NAT), it will replace the source IP address on the outgoing packets to the router with a different address, **hiding the IP addresses** of the devices (the original source addresses) from the modem.

The fact that the modem can see IP addresses does not mean it looks at them or uses them in any way, that depends on the type of modem and what other features are in the device called a modem.

To be sure on Q2, you would have to look at the specs of your modem and router and possibly check their configuration or default behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Gerben. So how does a "per device" firewall work (probably done on router?). Ex. I want device 1 to be blocked when it visits google.com but not device 2. How can this be done before the router?

Comment: A router knows about IP addresses, so it can apply rules that allow or deny traffic based on source and or destination IP.

Answer (score 2):

The subnet and any broadcast domain will end at the router, and the modem and any device upstream will not see any MAC addresses from device 1 or 2. It will only see a MAC address for the router. MAC addresses are used at layer 2, and only known inside a given broadcast domain. There are exceptions, such as proxy-arp, but under normal circumstances the router will be segmenting broadcast domains.

http://study-ccna.com/collision-broadcast-domain

As for the IP address, the modem is more of a "Layer 2 bridge" so if it has any awareness of a route to those devices IPs, it would be purely for management. Not a matter of function.

Answer (score -1):

A modem is a media converter.
Converts cable analog signals (or DSL) <> digital, viz. Ethernet.
Strictly a layer 1 device.
Preposterous and shows such ignorance to read on so many sites about IP addresses and other L3 items associated with a modem. There are none.